# R global and local variable from loops

Tags: r, global-variables, local

I have below code. How could I assign global variable a to b? In below case i want to assign global a (which contains "new") to b. But R assigns local a to b. Moreover is there any way to check value of the global variable with the function? If global a's value is "old" that i want to take some set of actions which are different from actions that i will take if a's value is "new"

```
a <- "old"
test <- function () {
  a="new1"
  a<<-"new"
  b<<-a
  print(paste("b is ",b))
}
test()
```

Comment: To check the value of global `a`, just test it before assigning a new value. Or use `get` and specify the environment you want. In general, global assignments inside a function are **strongly** discouraged. It would be better practice to pass `a` in to the function as an argument and assign the result of the function to `a`. `a <- test(a)`. If you need multiple returns, use a list.

Comment: Please show example of get and specifying the environment name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the line

```
b<<-a
```

into

```
b<<- get0("a", envir= parent.frame() )
```

should  do it. However, please take note of Gregor's comment  and see if this is really what you want.